# Copy a million record from excel to database

Tags: sql, excel, database, oracle

I have **1 million** records in my **excel sheet** and I want to copy those to **oracle** database in the fastest way possible.

I am aware of 2 ways one using **Batch** and other using **SQLBulkcopy**.

Is there a fastest way to do this apart from these 2 methods?

And also I have a requirement to create a `log file` which contains the details of records which were not inserted while doing the operation.

Comment: If you want the fastest method possible, then this should not be a Java / JDBC question.  Your tagging is implicitly limiting you to Java / JDBC solutions.

Comment: Convert it to CSV and load it using SQL* loader. I bet u it's fast.

Comment: This comment by @KaushikNayak is fastest and no need for « copy » just use oracle to open the csv file directiy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way will be to make the excel file type to CSV matching all the columns to the headers of the table and then manually importing the CSV  to the table.

Comment: Also drop indices befor importing/recreate them after importing.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way to load comma separated files on the remote server is to use direct path load through sql*ldr.. if on the same server you could use external tables as well..

I would recommend you to load using 2 steps.. 
first create a sql*ldr  load script by following the [blog](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/08/using-oracle-sql-developer-to-setup-sqlloader-runs/) .
Then run the generated script in oracle client..
If the table has nologging  then adding the append command before execution of the script will make it even faster..

Having said that, a million rows is too small for oracle and should be able to load under a minute if the table is not heavily indexed..

You can load even faster by loading in parallel, but thats a over kill for just a million rows.

Answer (score -1):

You can use any Excel parsing library, like apache-poi
It gives you the ability to read through excel spreadsheets.

Just store each row & column, as well as any other data you need.
Then, transfer all of that data to the server/location you wish to see it on.

Example source from one of my programs using this library:

```
public boolean read() {
    for (final int sheet : sheets()) {
        final Sheet result = workbook.getSheetAt(sheet);
        if (result != null) {
            results.addAll(results(result));
        }
    }
    if (results().size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Creating backup database incase any failures occur...");
        createBackup();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean open() {
    try {
        results = new HashSet<E>();
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(new File(location()))));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException getting workbook from speadsheet: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return results != null && workbook != null;
}
```

Comment: Ok great, but is this the fastest way possible out there? I mean approx how many minutes would it take to copy the entire sheet to db if we go by this route?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. But even if the code were somewhat complete, this is still not the best and definitely not the fastest approach.

Comment: @ghostrider Don't do this. Convert your Excel to CSV, upload to the db server, import using database CSV tools.

Comment: @lexicore but is that the fastest way or using the SQL loader will be the fastest as said in the comments?

Comment: @ghostrider There's no "or". SQL*Loader belongs to the "database CSV tools" set.